# Locate other people in my app android using google Maps

Tags: android, performance, google-maps, android-studio, location

I want an app that allow the user know the location of other people nearby using the same app (those people will know that other people will be able to see their location) in a radius of 20 km.

I have an idea of put the location of the people every minute on a web server but i will like to know if there is another way to do this

In case that there is not another way, what do you recommend me to do to have the best performance uploading those location to the web server and not overloading it

Answer (score 0):

please take a look at this link: https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html

I had the same issue a few months ago and it really helped me to move forward in my case...
Hope it helps..